# django share document with user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a my django site where admin user will have to share documents with other user type called accountant.for example admin has something called documents in the sidebar when clicked it shows the list of documents related to the admin beside every document we will have a button share when clicked it shows the list of accountants when selected and shared the documents will be listed on the accountant's documents list page.there are two different login interfaces.how can i achieve this i have model called Document and the user type model Accountant.how should the relations should be and what should be the logic in views.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    file = model.Filefield()


class Accountant(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is general you have to ask more specifically where exactly your problem is.

I guess you dint know how the relationship between models is going.
you can use many-to-many relationships to solve your problem.

something like this:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    file = model.Filefield()
    has_access_to = models.ManyToManyField(Accountant)
```

add like this:

```
# document_instance is a document object and accountant instace is the same
document_instance.has_access_to.add(accountant_instance)
```

for showing use this :

```
accountant_instance.document.all()
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i guess this should work but when u meant document_instance and accountant_instance i didn't got the point what exactly u were referring to

Comment: document_instance and account_instance are the objects you are pointing to.
for example, you have a document (document_instance) you want to pass the access of that to a specific account the account is an instance of a account model so i called that account instance you can name that what ever you want ;)